# How do I read this Syntax?

Tags: mysql, variables

I have a question interpret regarding to a syntax that I'm studying.

I do not understand how the sessional variable (`@variable`) work in this case.

I understand the logic of the syntax but I thought `@variable` is used something like below

```
SET @expired_date = STR_TO_DATE(expired_date, '%m/%d/%Y').
```

Can anyone explain why is the other way around?

Thank you for the help

[image]

Comment: Please review the section Input Preprocessing here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement you have shown:

```
SET @expired_date = STR_TO_DATE(expired_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

is to set a variable from the value of a column. In your `LOAD DATA INFILE` query a column is being set from the value of a variable. Specifically, the query reads the values from the csv file into

1. the column `title`;
2. the variable `@expired_date`; and
3. the column `amount`

and the value for the *column* `expired_date` is then generated from the `@expired_date` *variable* using `STR_TO_DATE`.